# What is a term for ineffective security measures that don't prevent any realistic attack?

Tags: account-security, terminology, security-theater

Is there a term for when you a particular system design might prove to have some advantages, but doesn't actually qualitatively change the potential attacks on the system and thus ends up as redundant, excessive, misleading, costly, and/or ineffective?

For example, a programmer might say, "We should make the user type in TWO passwords upon every login. We'll store one password in one database and the second password in a different database."

Many would deem a second password as unnecessary, as you could instead just increase password length or complexity. And it doesn't matter if the system allows unlimited password attempts or contains similar vulnerabilities. It also begs the question of "well, why not THREE password then?"

Although, having two passwords in separate databases certainly adds some sort of extra hurdle for an attacker, especially because a single database dump doesn't give you all sensitive information. But my impression is that, in practice, it is more secure to have a single source of truth for sensitive data that is as clear as possible, and then protect that data as well as possible. This is like the idea behind using a bastion host for SSH access: it turns out it is more secure to handle things in one spot, rather than leaving it to each host to secure itself, even though there may be a case where an attacker fails to gain access to a certain host having a coincidentally different SSH configuration.

Comment: "overengineering" comes to mind.

Comment: [security theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_theater) also comes to mind.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP used the tag that is its own answer to the question. If you read the `security-theater` tag you used, you will see that it describes what you asked.

Comment: @schroeder i disagree because the situation i described has some possible advantage and the intention isnt just for "show" or to make people feel good. i selected that tag because it was closely related, but i didnt feel it captured the intent of the behavior i described. that being said, if the term actually does mean exactly what i described, then i mightve just misunderstood how broad the meaning of "security theater" is.

Comment: The tag says "doing *little* or nothing". The situation you describe is a situation where very little is actually achieved. If one database can be dumped, there is no reason to believe that 2 cannot be, and unless there is a real reason to believe that it would be significantly harder, then this is security theatre. The dev feels good that they made the app more complex.